# Select only first occurrence of a recordset combination in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table with multiple rows combined like this

```
category1 | category2 | category3 | code    | price
fruit     | awesome   | green     | apple1  | 10.00
fruit     | awesome   | green     | apple1b | 14.00
fruit     | awesome   | red       | apple1  | 15.00
pasta     | good      | small     | pasta1  | 5.00
pasta     | good      | small     | pasta2  | 7.00
pasta     | awesome   | red       | pasta2  | 10.00
pizza     | margherita| good      | pizza1  | 20.00
```

And I need to put all the possibile combinations of category1, category2 and category3 in a database (one combination per row) like:

```
fruit | awesome    | green
fruit | awesome    | red
pasta | good       | small
pasta | awesome    | red
pizza | margherita | good
```

Avoiding duplicates. I tried with DISTINCT but of course it works only with unique occurencies. How should I do that in php?

Comment: define "first". And I don't understand your beef with DISTINCT

Comment: Why can't you just use `select distinct category1, category2, category3 from ...`? If you're only specifying those three then the distinct should give you what you want

Answer (score 3):

You can do that using this query:

```
select distinct category1, category2, category3 from categories;
```

You can see how it is done, and the results, in this SQL fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a423c/1

Answer (score 0):

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a7967/1

```
SELECT  t1.category1, t2.category2, t3.category3
FROM (
  SELECT DISTINCT category1
  FROM table1) t1
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT DISTINCT category2
    FROM table1) t2
ON 1
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT DISTINCT category3
    FROM table1) t3
ON 1
```

Comment: Looks like it works, don't know why it was down voted.

Comment: Because OP question is not very clear, so people didn't get OP goal